# Input Parameter for callback function Web3

Tags: javascript, web3js

I want to send the parameter to the function in smart contract i tried different ways but it keeps giving me error.

My solidity file is

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

 import "./ConvertLib.sol";

 contract Check {
 function multiply(uint a) public pure returns(uint){
    return a*a;
 }
}
```

I connected to Web3 sucessfully and created the instance of contract as inst. When i try to execute the function

```
 console.log(inst.multiply.call()(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

it gives me error

```
Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

and if i add argument like this

```
console.log(inst.multiply(2).call()(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

or like this

```
console.log(inst.multiply.call(2)(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

it gives me this error

```
Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter.
```

I am using Web3 version 0.20.3

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with the Hello World contract and after pulling my hairs for a while I tried something like:

```
console.log(inst.multiply(2, function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

That is, passing a callback function as the last parameter. As it says in the documentation, "all its functions [Solidity's] use synchronous HTTP requests by default. If you want to make an asynchronous request, you can pass an optional callback as the last parameter to most functions. All callbacks are using an error first callback style:"

```
web3.eth.getBlock(48, function(error, result){
   if(!error)
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
   else
       console.error(error);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
inst.methods\[multiply](2).call().then(data => ...).catch(err => {...})
```